# Why is this boost header file not included

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, compilation

I'm building my c++ program with cmake on a Mac. The compiler gives me following Error:

```
error: boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory
```

The line that triggers the error is the following:

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
```

or

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Which of the above I use doesn't changed the Error

But in my CMakeLists.txt I include the boost headers in the following way:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost) 
MESSAGE("Boost information:") 
MESSAGE("  Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}") 
MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}") 
MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}") 

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Boost include dirs is filled with "/opt/local/include/" during the cmake process and this folder contains a folder boost which contains the filesystem.hpp

Boost gives the following messages while generating the Makefile, I only copied the boost part:

```
-- Boost version: 1.38.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
Boost information:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /opt/local/include
Boost_LIBRARIES: 
Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: /opt/local/lib
-- Configuring done
```

While running make VERBOSE=1 This line contains the error:

```
cd /Users/janusz/Documents/workspace/ImageMarker/Debug/src && 
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -g -verbose -I/Users/janusz/Documents/workspace/ImageMarker/src/. -o CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/FaceRecognizer.cpp.o -c /Users/janusz/Documents/workspace/ImageMarker/src/FaceRecognizer.cpp
/Users/janusz/Documents/workspace/ImageMarker/src/FaceRecognizer.cpp:8:32: error: boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ImageMarker.dir/FaceRecognizer.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Do you understand why the compiler isn't picking the /opt/local/include directory?

If you need more information I'm happy to provide it

Comment: This looks fine, what does "ls /opt/local/include/boost/filesystem.hpp" say?

Comment: make sure the include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) is listed _before_ any add_executable or add_library statements are reached.

Comment: Thanks... that seems to help now I get a boost error at compile time. I added the subdirectory with the executable statement before the include, not aware that cmake will at that moment apply everything in that subdir. That solved at least this problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all use

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)
```

rather than

```
  FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
```

This way cmake will give you a nice error message if it doesn't find it, long before any compilations are started. If it fails set the environment variable BOOST_ROOT to /opt/local (which is the install prefix).
Additionally you will have to link in the filesystem library, so you want

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
```

for later use of

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

Enter

```
cmake --help-module FindBoost
```

at the shell to get the docs for the Boost find module in your cmake installation.

PS: An example

The CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Foo)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo 
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  vector<string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);
  if(args.empty())
  {
    printf("usage: ./foo SOME_PATH\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  fs::path path(args.front());

  if(fs::exists(path))
    printf("%s exists\n", path.string().c_str());
  else
    printf("%s doesn't exist\n", path.string().c_str());

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /opt/local/include

Comment: Please run
 
    $ make VERBOSE=1 

and show us the line where the file which fails is compiled

Comment: Please use http://pastebin.ca/ to send us a link to a full log of your actions :)

Comment: added the output from make. It seems that /opt/local/include isn't mentioned during the compiler call

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by adding some lines in my CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(MyResource)

function(myresources out_var)
    set(RESULT)
    foreach(in_f ${ARGN})
        file(RELATIVE_PATH src_f ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${in_f})
        set(out_f "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${in_f}.c")
        add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${out_f}
                COMMAND myresource ${out_f} ${src_f}
                DEPENDS ${in_f}
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
                COMMENT "Building binary file for ${out_f}"
                VERBATIM)
        list(APPEND result ${out_f})
    endforeach()
    set(${out_var} "${result}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
find_path(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRS boost/filesystem.hpp)

add_executable(myresource myresource.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myresource ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(myresource PUBLIC ${BOOST_FILESYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including **filesystem.hpp** without the "boost/" part?

Comment: All headers files in boost do their includes like  #include <boost/...>, so if <boost/filesystem.hpp> doesn't work, nothing works!