# Boost include headers not found using cmake

Tags: boost, cmake

This question is very similar to [Why is this boost header file not included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065011/why-is-this-boost-header-file-not-included), however the hints there don't (seem to) solve my problem.

I got a CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(jetorigin)

SET(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.43" "1.43.0" "1.44" "1.44.0" "1.45" "1.45.0")
SET(BOOST_ROOT "$ENV{HOME}/usr")
MESSAGE(STATUS "** Search Boost root: ${BOOST_ROOT}")
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.43 COMPONENTS filesystem regex REQUIRED)
 MESSAGE(STATUS "** Boost Include: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
 MESSAGE(STATUS "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
 MESSAGE(STATUS "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
```

And include some boost headers in my code like this:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
```

Now the output from cmake looks ok

```
-- ** Search Boost root: /home/oli/usr
-- Boost version: 1.43.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   regex
-- ** Boost Include: /home/oli/usr/include
-- ** Boost Libraries: /home/oli/usr/lib
-- ** Boost Libraries: /home/oli/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so;/home/oli/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so
```

But I get this error:

```
error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
```

(and similar for the other includes). Full output from make VERBOSE=1 can be found here http://pastebin.ca/2039425. It looks as though there is no -I flag added even though Boost_INCLUDE_DIR seems to be set correctly.

I'm using CMake 2.8.1 by the way.
I would very much appreciate any hints on what is going wrong here..

---

EDIT:
I've found the problem. Seems I pulled some ancient version of my standard CMakeLists.txt from the depths of my archives. It needs to be:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

(note the non-capitalized "Boost")...
Maybe older versions of CMake have been more tolerant in this respect or by bad luck I simply chose to start with a version of my CMakeLists.txt with an unfixed bug..

Comment: Oh damn. Nevermind, I found it..
See my edit above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cmake doesn't find Boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)

Comment: There is apparently a really big difference between `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR`. The former I was erroneously using; the latter fixed it. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify a mode for `find_package`, it attempts to first use `MODULE` mode, and then `CONFIG` mode. As per [the docs for the `FindBoost` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html#cache-variables), the cache variable storing the directory containing Boost headers is named `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` and not `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR`. As per [the CMake language docs' section on variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables), CMake variable names are case-sensitive. I don't know why you had another CMakeLists.txt file with `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR` working.